# What do you call a person who loves nuts and bolts?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, expressions

What do you call a person who has a fetish for fasteners such as bolts, nuts and screws?

Comment: I think he's **nuts**

Comment: … or perhaps has a **screw loose**.

Comment: *Ferrovore*, if the nuts and bolts are steel.

Comment: Perhaps _fastenated_?

Comment: How does this fetish manifest itself?

Answer (score 1):

A **tinkerer**: someone who enjoys small scale engineering and using his hands, and who loves the feel of low tech tools.

> [***tinker***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tinker)
>   to work in the manner of a tinker; *especially* :  to repair, adjust, or work with something in an unskilled or experimental manner :  [fiddle](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fiddle) <always *tinker**ing* with his car>

Note that "fetish" implies something a bit unhealthy or even sexual;
the word "tinkerer" does not have the same association.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be at the level of scope that you want,
but a [***gearhead***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gearhead) is

> a person who is very interested in mechanical or technical things
>   (such as cars or computers)